# Script to Convert Text to Font Enumeration for Indesign

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am attempting to expedite the process of coordinating fonts between translated comics (mainly CJK languages to English) in Adobe InDesign.

Beginning with a InDesign document in Language A, my company translates, typesets, and edits that comic in Language B. Eventually the initial document is totally scraped and its links are moved to a new document in a different arrangement (this is a reason behind my odd mission, but not super necessary to consider here). For all word balloons set in Font X in Language A, we want the corresponding balloons to be consistently set in Font X-Prime (a vibes-based equivalent) in Language B and sometimes C etc. Coordinating this between all parties working on a book is complicated, especially given that which fonts correspond between the two languages may change during the editing process.

To make this easier, editors often manually maintain 'font bibles' -- documents which show screen shot examples of a font in Language A and note which font it corresponds to. The final aim here is to create a more efficient means of crafting these font bibles and to make it easier to check that a book is accurate.

As for the actual step which is creating an issue: I want to create a script which, for each font, finds all text frames set in that font, and replaces their contents with a unique number corresponding to that font. The converted document would then be an easy and scalable way to check for matches between many languages (eg. by listing that Meiryo:1:Helvetica etc). Below is a mock up of the goal, where different shapes represent different fonts in Language A (forgive it being an ms paint doodle, can't share confidential works in progress).

[A mock up depicting text in various fonts, represented by shapes, being converted to numbers which represent the font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOWsT.png)

This can be accomplished by just manually making find and replace changes, but it that is rather tedious. At first, automating this seem relatively attainable even with my meager scripting skills, but every method I tried was not successful, frequently for reasons which are unclear to me.

Here is the script that is closest to being successful so far. The final alert would output to a file in a completed version. This code was intended to loop through all fonts in the document, and for each one, replace every block of text set in that font with the index of the font. Instead, on my test file, the code successfully enumerates through each of 25 fonts, says that it finds zero text for 24 of them, and successfully replaces only 1 of the fonts with its number. The issue might somehow be with the font styles, because the only font it is successful with has no style. But I have not been able to figure out a way to fix it based on that.

It may also be significant that many of the fonts in the documents this script will run on are broken links (we don't always have all the CJK fonts used by our licensors), but manual find and replace can work just fine with fonts like that.

We also can't use character or paragraph styles instead of fonts, as the original files have none.

```
var document = app.activeDocument;
var fonts = document.fonts;
var list = "FONTS: \n"

app.changeGrepPreferences.appliedFont = "Futura";
app.changeGrepPreferences.fontStyle = "Bold";
app.changeGrepPreferences.justification = Justification.CENTER_ALIGN;
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = NothingEnum.nothing;

for (index = 0; index < fonts.length; index++) {
                app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
                app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = index.toString();
                app.findGrepPreferences.appliedFont = fonts[index];
                list = list + app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo +" : "+ app.findGrepPreferences.appliedFont.toString() + "\n";
                alert(app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo + " : " + app.findGrepPreferences.appliedFont.toString() + " : " + document.changeGrep().length.toString());
                try { document.changeGrep(); } catch (e) { alert("error"); }
}

alert(list);
```

I have also approached this by trying to loop through document.textFrames, but I gave up on that before seeing any progress, as I can't figure out how to identify the font of the content in any given text frame.

Help is very much appreciated! This seemed like it would be an easy automation, but evidently there are not many other situations where text needs to be changed based on what font it is in, so I can't find a good parallel to base my code on anywhere online. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that should do the trick.
I had to build a list of font family names and a 2nd list of corresponding font style names. Creating these lists with everyItem() allows us to work around a bug (in InDesign 2021) where document.fonts[x].fontStyleName always returns document.fonts[0].fontStyleName.
We can then loop through the fonts and find text styled with a font and change that text to the index number of the font.

```
// Add alert to indicate the script is starting
alert("The script is starting...");

// Get the active document
var doc = app.documents[0];

// include master pages
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeMasterPages = true;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.searchBackwards = true;

// work around doc.fonts[i].fontStyleName bug by building
// a list of font properties using everyItem()
font_list_family = doc.fonts.everyItem().fontFamily;
font_list_style = doc.fonts.everyItem().fontStyleName;

// Loop through each font in the document and 
// use find/change to set the contents of the text style ranges with the current font name
// to the index of the current font name

for (var i = 0; i < doc.fonts.length; i++) {
    //Reset find/change preferences to default settings
    app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    // Use find/change to set the text to index of the current font name font_list_family array
    app.findGrepPreferences.appliedFont = font_list_family[i];
    app.findGrepPreferences.fontStyle = font_list_style[i];
    app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = (i+1).toString();
    doc.changeGrep();
}

// Add alert to indicate the script is complete
alert("The script is complete!");
```

Here's a way to do it without relying on InDesign's FindChange feature. Executing takes much longer, but it could help troubleshoot the issue.

```
// Get the active document
var doc = app.documents[0];

// Create an empty array to hold all the font names
var distinct_font_name_list = [];

var textStyleRanges = doc.stories.everyItem().textStyleRanges.everyItem().getElements();

// Loop through each text style range and add the applied font name to the distinct_font_name_list array if it doesn't already exist
for (var j = 0; j < textStyleRanges.length; j++) {
    var fontName = textStyleRanges[j].appliedFont.name;
    var exists = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < distinct_font_name_list.length; k++) {
        if (distinct_font_name_list[k] == fontName) {
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!exists) {
        distinct_font_name_list.push(fontName);
    }
}

// Loop through each unique font name in the distinct_font_name_list array
for (var i = 0; i < distinct_font_name_list.length; i++) {
        // redefine textStyleRanges because content changes will cause changes in references
        var textStyleRanges = doc.stories.everyItem().textStyleRanges.everyItem().getElements();
        for (var j=textStyleRanges.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (textStyleRanges[j].appliedFont.name == fontName) {
                // If the applied font name matches the current font name, 
                //set the contents of the text style range to 
                // the index of the current font name in the distinct_font_name_list array
                textStyleRanges[j].contents = (i+1).toString();
            }
        }
}

// Add alert to indicate the script is complete
alert("The script is complete!");
```

Comment: This is a significant improvement over what I had, thanks! But I am still encountering some issues. (+small typo of 'fontFamily.font_list_family[i]' should be 'font_list_family[i]'). Crucially in my trials, this did not catch all the fonts. If I added a line which set the font of the replacement to a standard font and ran it repeatedly, it would gradually pick up more and more of the missed fonts, but that ruins the indexing. I tried this on both a book with only CJK fonts and one with only English fonts, and had that missed font issue with both. I also got a 30477 error on the 3rd run on Eng.

Comment: The code works fine for me. I can't reproduce the problem. All I can think is try to run the change `doc.changeGrep();` several times. Just duplicate the line several times: `doc.changeGrep(); doc.changeGrep(); doc.changeGrep();`.

Comment: quickly adding 
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.searchBackwards = true;
to see if that helps. will share a different approach later.